# Enum in C for loops

Tags: c, for-loop, enums

Sorry guys, I am a beginner in programming and I am confused on how to correctly use enum value in for loops, I have done some research but couldn't understand completely. Basically, I want to check if the initialise board is empty. Thanks

```
enum contents
{
   Empty,
   Full,
   Half
};

void init(enum contents board[][WIDTH])
{
   int row,column;
   for(row=0;row<WIDTH; row++)
   {
     for(column=0; column<HEIGHT; column++)
     board[row][column] = ??;
    }
}
```

Comment: `=` is for assignment. Putting `= Empty` there would make the whole board empty.  Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: A function called `init` should be initializing, not checking

Comment: yes, its for initializing, my bad, so initialize the whole board to be empty would be `=Empty`?

Comment: Please show definition of `board`

Comment: Dont you think to specify where it comes from like `contents.Empty` ? Not sure.

Comment: what do you mean by definition? as in what it display to be like? its just like a board game with rows and columns.

Comment: @DrKoch it's an argument to the function, do you mean show where it gets called from and what with?

Comment: I expect to see a line like `long board[12][34];` in order to understand the *context* of your question.

Comment: since EMPTY _should_ be 0, it is sufficient to "init" it on initialization like `enum contents board[HEIGHT][WIDTH]={0};` - no function required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>         
#define HEIGHT 6
#define WIDTH 5

enum contents
{
    Empty,
    Full,
    Half
};

void init(int board[][WIDTH])
{
    int row,column;
    for(row=0;row<HEIGHT; row++)
        for(column=0; column<WIDTH; column++)
            board[row][column] = Full;
}

int main(void) {
    int board[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
    init(board);
    int row,column;
    for(row=0;row<HEIGHT; row++)
    {
        for(column=0; column<WIDTH; column++)
            printf("%d ",board[row][column]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code will segfault if `HEIGHT` is ever changed.

Comment: heh, sorry (copy, paste) I will repair it

Comment: Thank you @Andrew, just 1 question, in the for-loops, `column<WIDTH`? or is it a typo?

Comment: @hohoho I just addressed that.